# SSRS use same variables across reports in report set/package

Tags: variables, reporting-services, parameters

I have a set of 15 reports .  These reports are driven by the same two variables.  Is there no such thing as a shared variable in the same way there is a shared dataset?  Basically, I want these to be global variables for the 15 reports.  I just added 6 new combinations of these variables and it's very cumbersome to add them to each report.  I want to specify them once and have them carry over.

I would even be satisfied if I could create and paste a block of xml in the project instead of having to go into each report/each parameter and add six new lines.

I'm very new to this, so please let me know if I need to provide some other detail.

Thanks,

Joe McClure

Comment: There is no way I know of to do this.  You are on the right track though using Shared Datasets.  I often pick a @customer variable from a dataset that is shared called 'customers' and then just set up the variable the same.

Comment: As a workaround, I found where to copy/paste the code in the XML of each report. I did the long editing of the parameter I needed to update.  I searched for <ReportParameter="MyParameter"> to find the code.  I could collapse the node for copying, go to the next reports, repeat the process and paste over the whole node.  Not too bad!

Comment: SSRS doesn't have "shared variables", but to make future development easier you can create a template report in your project, with all required variables, then copy this as the basis for each new report.

Comment: Would it be possible to store the variable values in a table?  Create a query to get the values form the table in a dataset, then set the value of the value of the variable, using the 'Get values from a query'?